# Variance of binomial estimate mle

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

I have the estimator:

p=1/nt * ∑Xi

Not too sure how to go about finding the variance of it

Comment: I assume that $X_i \overset{\mbox{i.i.d.}}{\sim} Binomial(n,p)$ for $i=1, \cdots, t$.  Then just use basic results concerning the variance operator

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties